# mocking a prop passed to a child component

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, redux-form

I am new to jest. My component look like this.

```
class ComponentToTest extends React.Component {
    searchName = () => {
        return axios.get(...)
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(save)}>
                <SomeChildComponent searchName={ (searchTerm: string) => this.searchName(searchTerm)} />
            </Form>
        )
    }
}


`ComponentToTest.test.js`
it('should call `handleSubmit` with `save`', () => {
    const store = createStore((state) => state, { app: {} });
    const onSave = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(() => {});
    const props: any = { handleSubmit: onSave };
    const tree = mount(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ComponentToTest {...props} />
        </Provider>,
    );

    tree.find('button').simulate('submit');
    expect(onSave).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I am getting error after running this test. is there any way to mock the call to searchName and return promise?

Comment: Since you are using axios, maybe you can use `jests-mock-axios` to mock the `axios.get` call instead! The docs are helpful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-axios

Comment: You forgot to invoke `searchName` in the prop. It should be `searchName={ (searchTerm: string) => this.searchName(searchTerm)}`. Or better yet `searchName={this.searchName}`